# PostgreSQL create function that references a non existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm trying to define a function that references a temp table that will be defined in the future, but I'm getting the following error on creation:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_function();
CREATE FUNCTION test_function() 
RETURNS void AS $$
    SELECT * FROM temp_table
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

> ERROR:  relation "_temp_table" does not exist LINE 7:    FROM
>   temp_table

Is there a way to define a Postgresql function that referenes a table that doesn't exist?

I can create an empty temp table as part of the function creation - but it's a bit ugly...

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: You should to use plpgsql language. When I see your example, please, start with read documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Comment: Plus you can't say it returns void but then make it return everything from your table.

Comment: I think your comments are slightly off topic here... I was making a point with my example regarding the issue I had with a nonexisting table - there's no point in this function anyway...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`check_function_bodies`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CHECK-FUNCTION-BODIES) to turn off the references while loading the functions, as it is done by pg_dump.

```sql
set check_function_bodies = off;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_function();
CREATE FUNCTION test_function() 
RETURNS void AS $$
    //your code actually doing something with tables/functions that don't exist yet
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

set check_function_bodies = on;
```

Comment: Thank you, really helpfull!